# Run NativeScript Vue on Android Device(USB)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I installed nativescript-vue on my computer, everything is OK!
But when I want to run the application on my android device (usb) using "**NativeScript Playground QR App**", it gives me this error code :

**>tns run android --bundle**

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.preview/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js, line: 75, column: 14

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 75, column: 15
    Frame: function:'FrameBase.navigate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 119, column: 30
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 863, column: 30
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 722, column: 14
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 20, column: 25


    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js, line: 75, column: 14

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 75, column: 15
    Frame: function:'FrameBase.navigate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 119, column: 30
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 863, column: 30
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 722, column: 14
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 20, column: 25


    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1116)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:996)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:983)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:18)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
    ... 9 more
```

I modified on the tns-android version, but the problem still exists ...
Please can you help me ?

Comment: Are you using NativeScript CLI 5.0? Does this error occur in the default template without any of your code changes?

Comment: @Manoj Yes, this error occur in the default template.

Comment: @Manoj after removing and install node_modules, it gives me a different error :   com.tns.NativeScriptException  ...  Failed to find module: "nativescript-vue-devtools" relative to :app/tns-modules .
But nativescript-vue-devtools is declared in my package.json file

Comment: Remove `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`, `platforms` and `hooks` to clean the project, and then run `npm install` and `tns run android --bundle` again to rebuild the project. This should resolve the issue. (I suspect there was an issue with the initial `npm install` and the `node_modules` folder was corrupted).

Comment: @AdamDev How did you fix this? I am having the same issue and can't fix it.